# Convert sql to tuple relational calculus

Tags: sql, tuples, tuple-relational-calculus

I'm trying to convert an sql query into tuple relational calculus, but there is a `NOT EXIST` that causes me to be stuck.

SQL query:

```
SELECT num FROM a a1, b b1
WHERE a1.num = b1.no AND a1.name = "Tim"
AND NOT EXIST
    (SELECT * FROM a a2, b b2
     WHERE a2.num = b2.no AND a2.name = "Tim" 
     AND b2.rating > b1.rating)
```

I already started with:

```
{ t: num | ∃a1 ∈ a ∃b1 ∈ b [ t(num) = a1(num) ∧ a1.name = "Tim" ∧ ¬∃a2 ∈ a ...
```

this is where I'm stuck. How do I show that it is `NOT EXISTS` from both `a2` and `b2`? If I write `¬∃a2 ∈ a ¬∃b2 ∈ b` then this is going to be a doubly nested sql query and not the one listed above.

Comment: Don't you mean (for your particular calculus notation to be consistent) `a1(name) = "Tim"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want there to not exist `a2` and `b2` per the `WHERE`.

SQL expression

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a a2, b b2 WHERE ...)
```

corresponds to tuple calculus expression

```
¬(∃ a2 ∈ a ∃ b2 ∈ b [...])
```

In SQL there `EXISTS` a row in the subquery if and only if there exist `a2` and `b2` row values per its `WHERE` to form that row. So `NOT EXISTS` such an SQL `a2` plus `b2` pair when it's not the case that there are calculus `a2` and `b2` where `...` .